# VHDL bidirectional bus mismatch

Tags: vhdl

i have a module with 16bit inout bus. In my top level entity i only want to connect 4 of them (also inout bidirectional). Connecting them directly results in an error ofcourse

```
port map( IO16bit => IO4bit )
```

so i connected the m through an internal signal

```
signal temp : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
port map(IO16bit => temp);
IO4bit <= temp(3 downto 0);
```

but now i get the error: 
Tri-state nodes do not directly drive top-level pins
and converted fanout into an OR gate

i lost the bidirectionality here. 
How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a range in the `port map`, and then connect the remaining to a `dummy` like:

```
signal dummy : std_logic_vector(15 downto 4) := (others => 'Z');
...
port map(
  IO16bit( 3 downto 0) => IO4bit,
  IO16bit(15 downto 4) => dummy,
...
```

That will compile for simulation, but you have to check that your synthesis tool of choice can also accept the construction, and handle it correctly.  It is often a problem to have internal `inout` ports in a synthesizable design.

Comment: Or even `IO16bit(15 downto 4) => open,` without the dummy signal. If you use a dummy signal, drive it with `(others => 'Z')` to prevent bus crashes

Comment: @BrianDrummond: If using `open` instead of `dummy` then ModelSim gives error "Formal "az_io" must not be associated with OPEN when subelements are associated individually.".  Good point with `Z` for dummy.